# How to determine the order of the real roots of a cubic equation?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, cubics, roots-of-cubics

This is a self-answered question (I didn't find a reference, and thought of documenting this). Consider the equation
$$
t^3+pt+q=0.
$$
Its discriminant is
$$
\Delta=-(4p^3+27q^2).
$$

Suppose that it has **three distinct real** roots; [this is equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Nature_of_the_roots) $\Delta > 0$, or $4p^3+27q^2<0$.

*In particular, this forces $p<0$.*

These roots [can be expressed as follows :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions)
$$
x_k=2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\frac{3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right)-k\frac{2\pi}{3}\right),
$$
where $k=0,1,2$.

---

**Claim:**
$$
x_0 > x_1 > x_2.
$$

How to prove this claim?

---

*Comment:*

In order to apply $\arccos$ we must have
$$-1 \le\frac{3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}} \le 1,$$

which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{27q^2}{-4p^3} \le 1.
$$
Since $p<0$, we can multiply this inequality by $-4p^3$, so it's equivalent to
$$
27q^2 \le -4p^3,
$$
or $\Delta \ge 0$.

Comment: If $p$ is always going to be negative, it'd be a lot cleaner (and clearer) to consider the equation $t^3 - p t + q = 0$ (or even $t^3-3pt + 2q = 0$) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three numbers $x_k=t\cos\left(\theta-k\frac{2\pi}3\right)$ ($k=0,1,2$) are supposed to be distinct and $t$ is positive.

Moreover, since $\theta\in[0,\pi/3],$ we have
$$\cos\theta-\cos\left(\theta-\frac{2\pi}3\right)=-2\sin\left(\theta-\frac\pi3\right)\sin\frac\pi3\ge0$$
and
$$\cos\left(\theta-\frac{2\pi}3\right)-\cos\left(\theta-\frac{4\pi}3\right)=-2\sin(\theta-\pi)\sin\frac\pi3\ge0.$$
Therefore,
$$x_0>x_1>x_2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer!:) I really didn't think of using trigonometric identities, very nice. BTW, if I am not mistaken, it should be $\sin(\pi/3)$ not $\sin(2\pi/3)$ at both $\sin$ products.

Comment: @AsafSchachar Thank you, you are right, I edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set
$$
m:=\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\frac{3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right),
$$
we have $0 \le m \le \pi/3$. (since the range of $\arccos$ is $[0,\pi]$).

The analysis in the question shows that $\Delta >0$ if and only if $-1<\frac{3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}<1$, which is equivalent to the strict inequality $0<m<\pi/3$.

Then, up to a multiplication by the positive constant of $2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}$, we have
$$
x_k=\cos\left(m-k\frac{2\pi}{3}\right),
$$
or
$$
x_0=\cos(m), x_1=\cos(m-\frac{2\pi}{3}),x_2=\cos(m-\frac{4\pi}{3}).
$$
Thus, $x_0 > x_1 > x_2$ is equivalent to
$$
\cos(m) >\cos(m-\frac{2\pi}{3})>\cos(m-\frac{4\pi}{3}),
$$
for any $m \in (0,\pi/3)$.

This can by differentiating the inequality $\cos(x) >\cos(x-\frac{2\pi}{3})$ and observing that the difference is monotone on $(0,\pi/3)$, and similarly for the second inequality.